# Opacity in IE8 not set properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I have following inline style set for my IE8 code :

```
filter:  alpha (opacity=0).
```

But it's not taking it properly in IE8. how do I resolve the issue?

Comment: What other style properties are applied? What is the element type? Does it ["have layout"](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)?

Comment: It doesn't have any layout. Element type is a span. element.style {
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
width: 80px;
position: absolute;
opacity: 100;
height: 35px;
font-size: 14px;
}.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE8 right now so i can't test it on my end but you can check it 
    -ms-filter: “alpha(opacity=75)”; /* ie 8 */ 

    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* ie lt 7 */

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following:

```
selector {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* internet explorer */
    opacity: 0.5;           /* fx, safari, opera, chrome */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)"; /*IE8*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.alpha img{
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -moz-opacity: 0;
 opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but maybe somebody else feels you should add some explanation. Editing your answer would enable them to undo the downvote.